# clash between class name and enum value: resolvable without namespaces?

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces, name-clash

```
class cippa{};

enum close{ cippa };

int main(){
    new cippa();    //bad here
}
```

Using `::cippa` doesn't help either. Is there a way to solve this without putting either the `enum` or the `class` in a separate `namespace`?

Comment: You could use `enum class`.

Comment: Question - why not have different names?

Comment: Side: You don't need `new` to instantiate a class.

Comment: Tell me: Why do you think that having the same name in one namespace twice might be a good idea?

Comment: Answer - because I'm exporting the class to a minimal scripting language, for implementation details it needs an enum, and I want to keep the same name for readability. And you shouldn't mind, by the way, the question itself is legit.

Answer (score 4):

Disambiguate using `new class cippa`. If a class name and enumerator (or function/variable) name is declared in the same scope, the class name is hidden. You can access it by `class name`. Same if the type name is an enumeration name. You could access that by `enum name`

```
#include <unistd.h>

// oops, close is now hidden! but we know a trick..
enum close c = cippa;
```

Comment: thanks. By the way, the shortly-lived answer with the C++11 `enum class` was interesting too.

Comment: +1, but as far as I know, it's generally considered bad style to include standard library headers after defining your own types. :)

Comment: wait, i happened to misread your enum name as *close*, but you named it `cose`. Oh well, never mind xD

Answer (score 1):

With C++11, if you do

```
class cippa;
enum class close { cippa };
```

then class `cippa` and and enum value `close::cippa` will not clash.

By the way that is essentially doing

```
class close{
public:
  enum enum_t{cippa};
};
```

But then instead of `close` you need to use `close::enum_t` to access the enum type. 
`close::cippa` remains the same.